# C Programming Read file and store it as a string

Tags: c, file

I wrote c code which input value for my program comes from here :

```
char *input[] = {"This input string value !!!", NULL};
```

But how can I read this value from the file (e.g. input.txt)? Is it possible to get the file content like a string?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes its possible. [**read this**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a file line-by-line, the easiest way to go is using `getline`.  Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) for a detailed description and a good code example.

`getline` will do all the low-lvel plumbing work of allocating buffers, copying data and scanning for newline characters, etc for you.  Keep in mind that this is only possible since `getline` uses dynamically allocated memory that you'll need to free again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[100];

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // Checks if the file was opened successfully
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Failed to open the file\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    // fgets here reads an entire line or 99 characters (+1 for \0) at a time, whichever comes first
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Line read = %s\n", buffer);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

You can also use `fgetc()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // Checks if the file was opened successfully
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fputs("Failed to open the file\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    // fgetc reads each character one by one until the end of the file
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("Character read = %c\n", ch);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, there one problem you gave limited number of elements for array how can do it not limited because I don't know the size f content it will be different every time. The next thing is fgets(var, 50, file); 50 is limit of read character? How can I make it without any limitations? Thanks!

Comment: Use `fgetc` then...I'll update my answer

Comment: What about char var[100]; How to make it dynamically?

Comment: To allocate it dynamically,use `malloc()` like this : `char *ch;ch=(char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));`

Comment: The value in the call to `fgets` does *not* limit the string length that you can read with it. Read its [description](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Comment: Why do I get Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Comment: @JoanaF. I've edited the code in the answer. Try it out. If you still have the crash issue, post a new question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

On recent Posix compliant systems you could use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), something like

```
FILE *fil = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");
if (!fil) {perror("somefile.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
char*linbuf = NULL; 
size_t siz = 0;
ssize_t linlen = 0;
while ((linlen=getline(&linbuf, &siz, fil))>0) {
   // linbuf contains the current line
   // linlen is the length of the current line
   do_something_with(linbuf, linlen);
};
fclose(fil);
free(linbuf), linbuf=NULL;
linlen = 0, siz = 0;
```